# Empty all files in subdirectories to parent directory

Tags: files, directory, mv

I have a parent directory (/Users/Me/Desktop/Songs) in which I manually drag&drop-sorted a bunch of reference material into folders. I just want to dump them all back. Is there a simple way to do this without having to invoke each sub-directory (band name)?

```
ls -d */
Belle & Sebastian - Cuckoo/
Belle & Sebastian - Fox in the Snow/
Belle & Sebastian - Get Me Away From Here I'm Dying/
Belle & Sebastian - If You Find Yourself Caught In Love/
Belle & Sebastian - If You're Feelin Sinister/
Belle & Sebastian - Like Dylan In The Movies/
Belle & Sebastian - Lord Anthony/
Belle & Sebastian - Me and the Major/
Belle & Sebastian - Piazza New York Catcher/
Belle & Sebastian - Sleep the Clock Around/
Blink 182 - Adam's Song/
Blue Oyster Cult - (Don't Fear) The Reaper/
Bob Dylan - Don't Think Twice (It's Alright)/
Bob Dylan - Things Have Changed/
Bobby Womack - California Dreamin'/
Bright Eyes - First Day Of My Life/
Bruce Springsteen - I'm On Fire /
Cat Stevens -  Wild World/
Chairlift - Bruises/
Collin Huggins - My Heart Belongs To You/
Company of Thieves - Oscar Wilde/
David Bowie -  Space Oddity/
Death Cab for Cutie - I Will Follow You into the Dark/
Destroyer - I Want This Cyclops/
Destroyer - Its Gonna Take An Airplane/
Destroyer - No Cease Fires/
Dirt Nasty - 1980/
Dispatch - General/
Edie Brickell & New Bohemians - Circle/
Once Upon A December – Anastasia/
The Lumineers - Ho Hey/
The Mountain Goats - No Children/
The Mountain Goats - Love Love Love/
The Mountain Goats - This Year/
The Petshop Boys - Go West/
The Postal Service - Nothing Better/
The Postal Service - Recycled Air/
The Postal Service - Sleeping In/
The Postal Service - The District Sleeps Alone/
The Postal Service - This Place Is A Prison/
Youth Lagoon - 17/
```

Answer (score 0):

[found answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182870/268379)

This did exactly what I wanted using mv and wildcards

```
mv /Users/Me/Desktop/Songs/Arrangements/*/* /Users/Me/Desktop/Songs/Arrangements
```

I was then able to delete the vestigial directories with

```
rm -dr */
```

Any feedback on method or syntax would be greatly appreciated.